# loop over rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im using python, and i have some difficulties to loop over rows in python.
my dataframe contains 3 columns : id, val1, size.
i want to create column col1 based on size.
Il trying this code and my code is never inside the first condition . How should i correct it please. Let's say that i don't won't something working with other method, im trying just to cirrect my own code.

Friendly,

**Sample of data**

```
data = [['x1', 100, 1], ['x2', 200, 2], ['x3', 300, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', 'val1', 'size'])
```

**code**

```
if (df['size'] == 2) is True:
  df['col1'] = df['val1']
  print("1")
else:
  pass
```

Comment: you don't have a loop here though

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: Are you want Printing, because you can do with out for-loop?

Answer (score 4):

Do you want `print`? You can do that without loop like below:

```
df['col1'] = np.where(df['size'] == 2, df['val1'], np.nan)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    id  val1    size    col1
0   x1  100     1   NaN
1   x2  200     2   200.0
2   x3  300     1   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['col1'] = df.loc[df['size'] == 2, 'val1']
print(df)
```

```
   id  val1  size   col1
0  x1   100     1    NaN
1  x2   200     2  200.0
2  x3   300     1    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make col1 if you edit your code like this:

```
data = [['x1', 100, 1], ['x2', 200, 2], ['x3', 300, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'val1', 'size'])

col1 = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['size'] == 2:
        col1.append(row['val1'])
    else:
        col1.append(None)
df['col1'] = pd.Series(col1)

print(df)
```

Another way is:

```
def func(df):
    if df['size'] == 2:
        return df['val1']
    else:
        return None

df['col1'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
print(df)
```

This will print:

```
   id  val1  size   col1
0  x1   100     1    NaN
1  x2   200     2  200.0
2  x3   300     1    NaN
```

Comment: i saw that you did a loop . Here is an example of ietrating that i did without loop           **def funt1(df):
        if (df['size'] == 2 ):
            val = 'Valu1'
        else: 
            val= 'Valu2'
        return val
df['col1'] = df.apply(funt1, axis=1)**

Comment: do you now why in this case i can did it and the first case does not iterate? thank you @Sangkeun Park

Comment: @tamo007 You can do it but, it should make the code like this. I added another way as you want to make it work

Comment: @SangkeunPark - never use `apply` here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584